# Swift error, cannot convert type Int to int 16

Tags: ios, swift

This function compares the number with the sum of the cubes of the components of this number. For example abc=a^3 + b^3 + c^3. There is an error converting, please help.

```
func triKuba ( i:Int16, k:Int16, var array:[Int16]=[] ) ->Int16{

    for var i=100;i<1000; i++ {
        array.append(Int16(i))
        if array[i] == pow(array[i]/10) + pow(array[i]/100) + pow(array[i]%10)  {
            return array[i]
        } else {
            return 0
        }
    }
}
 triKuba(0, k: 0)
```

next error in line around method pow 'Cannot invoke pow with argument list of type Int16' if I understood correctly, method pow is a^3

Comment: line: array.append(i)
Error: Cannot convert value of type Int to expected argument type Int16

Comment: What about method pow?

Comment: Its very unclear what you're trying to do in this function. using array.append(i) will add i to the end of an array, if the array is empty and you append one element to it, it will be one element long, in the next line you are subscripting with the value 1, which in the first iteration is 100, which would cause an index out of bounds error

Comment: I'm trying to check all three-digit numbers according to the rule abc=a^3 + b^3 + c^3

Comment: pow is a method that two floating point numbers and returns a result which is the first number to the power of the second number e.g. pow(2, 3) returns 2^3 which is 8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I strongly suspect this is what you are looking for:

```
func arithmeticRoot3(var value: Int) -> Int {
    var result = 0

    while value > 0 {
        let digit = value % 10
        result += digit * digit * digit
        value /= 10
    }

    return result
}

func triKuba() -> [Int] {
    return (100...999).filter() {
        $0 == arithmeticRoot3($0)
    }
}

print(triKuba()) // [153, 370, 371, 407]
```

Comment: Excellent code. I will begin programming..So what is mean "$0 == arithmeticRoot3($0)"? You can answer in Russian :)

Comment: It's an English site :).  `$0 == arithmeticRoot3($0)` is a closure with a [shorthand argument](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH11-ID100) passed to a [filter](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_SequenceType_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/intfm/SequenceType/s:FeRq_Ss12SequenceType_SsS_6filteruRq_S__Fq_FzFzqqq_S_9GeneratorSs13GeneratorType7ElementSbGSaqqq_S_9GeneratorS0_7Element_) method of a `Range<Int>` value.

Comment: The whole thing just iterates over all integers from 100 to 999 and filters only those that are equal to the sum of cubes of their digits.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than just solving your issue, I'm going to explain what the problem is, and **why it throws an error**. With this information you should be able to fix the issue (and similar ones in the future!).

In Swift, you can't always do things like multiply an Int with a Float, or return an Int16 from a Double type return function. To you, it might be obvious that *'casting'* the variable to the intended type would be fine - but *the compiler doesn't know that*.

If you're sure it will be safe, you can 'cast' variables to the required type:

```
Int(int16Variable) // int16Variable has been casted to an 'Int'.
```

Answer (score 0):

The method you posted had several syntax issues. I fixed them. Working method below:

```
func triKuba ( i:Int16, k:Int16, var array:[Int16]=[] ) ->Int16{

    for var i=100;i<1000; i++ {
        array.append(Int16(i))

        if Double(array[i]) == pow(Double(array[i])/10, 3.0) + pow(Double(array[i]/100), 3.0) + pow(Double(array[i]%10), 3.0)  {
            return array[i]
        } else {
            return 0
        }
    }
}
```

Error you were getting was about missing cast from `Int` to `Int16(i)`

Comment: What about method pow? Like this.
if array[i] == pow(array[i]/10) + pow(array[i]/100) + pow(array[i]%10)
I have error:Cannot invoke pow with an argument list type of Int16. pow is a cube?

Comment: What's wrong with pow method? I can't see it in your code?

Answer (score -1):

in your for loop you are declaring a new `i` variable which is implied to be of type `Int` as opposed to `Int16`. (Due to shadowing this is the variable being used in your function body, the parameter `i` you pass in is never being used.

I would advise either changing the type for your function parameters to be of type `Int` like so:

```
func triKuba (var i: Int, var k: Int, var array: [Int]=[] ) -> Int {
```

or cast your `Int16` variables to `Ints` like so:

```
array.append(Int16(i))
```